# What are MsiTriState LinkToFile and MsiTriState SaveWithDocument meaning in adding picture to excel C#

Tags: c#, excel

So, i wanted to add picture to excel from c#. I found there are two parameters with MsoTriState(MsoTriState LinkToFile and MsoTriState SaveWithDecument) which u can fill with MsoTriState.msoFalse and MsoTriState.msoTrue.[These are the required parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkC5k.png). I'm so confused about the meaning of both of it. Like what happen if we fill the MsoTriState LinkToFile with MsoTriState.msoFalse or maybe true, and the MsoTriState SaveWithDocument too.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addpicture) says about `SaveWithDocument`: This argument must be `msoTrue` if `LinkToFile` is `msoFalse` The example on that page says you can both link to file and save to document, in which case the link can update the picture when it can reach it, but will have a cached copy when it can't.

Comment: @NetMage thanks, the documentation is really hopeful.